# Is this proof I wrote correct and what's wrong if not?

Tags: haskell

I already asked a different question realted to this proof, so I'm sorry for duplicate. Just nobody would answer any more, because the other one has an answer.

I am trying to prove the following statement by structural induction:

```
foldr f st (xs++yx) = f (foldr f st xs) (foldr f st ys)        (foldr.3)
```

These are the definitions of foldr:

```
foldr f st [] = st                                             (foldr.1)
foldr f st x:xs = f x (foldr f st xs)                          (foldr.2)
```

Now I want to start working on the base case passing the empty list to xs. I have this, but I don't know if it is correct.

```
foldr f st ([]++ys) = f (foldr f st []) (foldr f st ys)
LHS:
    foldr f st ([]++ys) 
  = foldr f st ys                                              by (++) and by (foldr.1)
RHS:
    f (foldr f st []) (foldr f st ys) = 
  = f st (foldr f st ys)                                       by (foldr.1)
  = foldr f st ys                                              by def of st = 0 and f = (+)

LHS = RHS, therefore base case holds
```

Now this is what I have for my inductive step:

```
Assume that:
  foldr f st (xs ++ ys) = f (foldr f st xs) (foldr f st ys)        (ind. hyp)

Show that:
  foldr f st (x:xs ++ ys) = f (foldr f st x:xs) (foldr f st ys)

LHS:
    foldr f st (x:xs ++ ys)  
  = f x (foldr f st (xs++yx))                                      (by foldr.2)
  = f x (f (foldr f st xs) (foldr f st ys) )                       (by ind. hyp)
  = f (f x (foldr f st xs)) (foldr f st ys)                        (by assosiativity of f)

RHS:
    f (foldr f st x:xs) (foldr f st ys) 
  = f (f x (foldr f st xs)) (foldr f st ys)                        (by foldr.2)

LHS = RHS, therefore inductive step holds. End of proof.
```

I am not sure if this proof is valid. I need some help in determining if it correct and if not - what part of it is not.

Comment: It's incorrect.  If you're doing induction you have to choose one variable to do induction over.  You seem to have chosen xs, which makes the base case `foldr f st ([]++yx) = f (foldr f st []) (foldr f st ys)`.

Comment: I am going to edit the base case. Is it only the base case that is incorrect?

Comment: homework? hard to believe that you have to prove something about foldr, but "no definition was provided".

Comment: There are some mistakes in your code. Do you need this to be valid code?

Comment: I need it to be a valid proof.

Comment: the definitions are foldr.1 and foldr.2

Comment: Maybe you need to write `==` instead of `=` in several places

Comment: @RumenHristov I only looked at the base case.  It was all I needed to look at to answer your question. :)  But the inductive step looks quite wrong too.

Comment: ok. So what exactly is wrong? I need some direction. I already knew that it was wrong.

Comment: @augustss I updated the base case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upd: The question was edited multiple times. The following makes sense in [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26969494/1) of the question.

This is not possible to prove. You need `f` to be a monoid: `f a (f b c) == f (f a b) c` with `f a st == a` and `f st a == a`.

A provable statement would be `foldr f st (xs++ys) == foldr f (foldr f st ys) xs`

---

Assuming `f` with `st` define a monoid, we get the following statements:

```
foldr f st ([]++ys) ==
     -- by definition of neutral element of list monoid, []++ys == ys
                    == foldr f st ys
     -- by definition of neutral element of `f` monoid, f st a == a
                    == f st (foldr f st ys)
     -- by definition of foldr, (foldr f st []) == st
                    == f (foldr f st []) (foldr f st ys)
```

Then,

```
foldr f st ((x:xs)++ys) ==
     -- by associativity of list monoid, (x:xs)++ys == x:(xs++ys)
                    == foldr f st (x:(xs++ys))
     -- by definition of foldr, foldr f st (x:t) == f x (foldr f st t)
                    == f x (foldr f st (xs++ys))
     -- by induction, foldr f st (xs++ys) == f (foldr f st xs) (foldr f st ys)
                    == f x (f (foldr f st xs) (foldr f st ys))
     -- by associativity of monoid `f`, f x (f y z) == f (f x y) z
                    == f (f x (foldr f st xs)) (foldr f st ys)
     -- by definition of foldr, f x (foldr f st t) == foldr f st (x:t)
                    == f (foldr f st (x:xs)) (foldr f st ys)
```

In essence, this is the proof of the monoid homomorphism. Lists being a free monoid, the homomorphism exists, and is exactly of the form you are seeking - it is the catamorphism for `f`.

Comment: Thanks very much man. I figured it in the same time when you were writing it here. And when I saw your proof, it is essentially the same as mine. I updated the above proof to reflect my interpretation, but it is the same as yours. I believe what I have above is now correct. Thank you very very much. It was such a great help to be able to compare to a known good solution.

Comment: @RumenHristov sure, now it does look very similar. It must be noted my answer is to revision 1 of your question, and even in the revision 4 of the question, you need to start with the assertion that `f` together with `st` and the type of list elements are a monoid - otherwise the statements about associativity of `f` and neutrality of `st` come out of the blue.

Answer (score 4):

before you start to prove something, check  a few examples, e.g.,

```
xs = ys = [] ; st = True ; f _ _ = False
```

Comment: I don't even know what you are talking about.

Comment: @RumenHristov this is a counterexample to your claim. If both lists are empty, `st` is a true boolean, and `f` is constantly false your claim does not hold. Hence, no proof of it can exist.